# Why are these two DIVs not aligned?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="s0">
    <div class="s1"></div><div class="s2">Some text</div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.s0 {
  width:300px;
  background-color:gray;
}

.s1 {
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.s2 {
  width:140px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:green;
}
```

If you test this code you'll see the two DIVs are not aligned.

You can check this out here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/memanuele/aUdPs/2/

If I remove the text from the green DIV the problem goes away.

Could someone please explain me why this happens? Sorry if this has already been asked, but I couldn't find my exact same issue in any other question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be easier to float the divs

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aUdPs/4/ - with floats

Answer (score 2):

Ah, it's a vertical-align problem.

Do

```
.s1, .s2 {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This will set both divs to align to the top of the parent.

(or if you want, you can `vertical-align` middle, bottom).

Alternatively, you can v-align one or the other DIV to top. You could also consider `float` property if you're going for a columnar layout.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. I was just wondering what's the logic behind this behavoir...

Comment: @emanuele that is just the default behaviour of inline-block elements. Think `images` as natively they are inline-block.

Answer (score 2):

**Understanding the Vertical Alignment Behavior**

Consider the following three examples:

```
<h2>Example 1</h2>
<div class="s0 ex1">
    <div class="s1"></div><div class="s2">Some text</div>
</div>

<h2>Example 2</h2>
<div class="s0 ex2">
    <div class="s1">A word</div><div class="s2">Some text</div>
</div>

<h2>Example 3</h2>
<div class="s0 ex3">
    <div class="s1"></div><div class="s2">Some text</div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.s0 {
  width:300px;
  background-color:gray;
}
.s1 {
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-right:10px;
}
.s2 {
  width:140px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:green;
}
.ex3 div {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

In Example 1, you have a block level element `.s0` with two child inline-block elements (`s1` and `s2`).  The two inline block elements are positioned along the baseline of the parent element.  In the case of `s1`, the baseline is the bottom margin edge of the element since the element has no text, hence, no inflow content as explained in the specification:

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align

If there were text in `s1` as in Example 2, then the baseline of `s1` is the bottom edge of the inline text box.

If you apply the `vertical-align` property to `top` (as stated in previous answers), then that fixes the problem as shown in Example 3.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/vY35c/

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
.s0 {
  width:300px;
  background-color:gray;
  display:inline-block;
}

.s1 {
  float:left;
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.s2 {
  float:right;
  width:140px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline;
  background-color:green;
}
```

It worked for me on the fiddle.
I added a `display: inline-block;` to `.s0` changed `display` from `inline-block` to `inline` for the s1 and s2 and floated `.s1` left and `.s2` right

You could do that or you could do:

```
.s1, .s2 {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Either one works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `float: right;` to `.s2` div class fixes the issue.